# helping php and ruby on rails coexist

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, moodle

I have a RoR app running on a server using Apache as the web server. I also have an instnace of moodle, an LMS based on PHP running. I have placed the web root of moodle inside the RoR space and for the most part it is working ok.

Inside moodle, if I go to sitename.com/moodle/my RoR intercepts that request and reports that it cannot find the page. If I go to sitename.com/moodle/my/index.php it works fine.

I tried creating a new virtual server but adding a second server running on 443 didnt work (the RoR based site is all under ssl).

Does anyone know of a way to tell RoR to ignore the moodle dir or get RoR to automatically detect and append the index.php to the path.

Comment: RoR is not intercepting the request, Apache is forwarding the request to RoR. You'll need to direct requests made to certain paths or subdomains or what-have-you (depends on your setup) to the PHP files over the RoR application. Also, you should understand that Rails is not the application server, but whichever server you've setup to host your Rails application (WEBrick is the default, unless you changed it). That's just semantics though.

Comment: OK, that is a very helpful reply. This tells me that the solution is not inside RoR but rather a directive is needed in the Apache config. Thanks for your help. Now I will look into httpd.conf directives that may alleviate the symptom. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! Glad that insight was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me to had a same issue below is the apache2 config for the same kind of issue as describe below.
Example folder is the rails application folder and "/en/blog" are the folder path in public folder of rails application in which i had a wordpress install so below configuration allow's apache to turn off passenger for a request made to "http:/example.com/en/blog" so this request is not process by passenger and this request is service as a normal php request so i was able to have a wordpress blog and a rails application running on same server.

# !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!

```
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

  #RailsEnv production      
  <Directory /var/www/example/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>

  <Location /en/blog>
     PassengerEnabled off
     <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /en/blog/
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /en/blog/index.php [L]
     </IfModule>
  </Location>
```